# How can I make sublime text autoindent Latex?

Tags: sublime-text

In c++ or java I can make sublime reindent the code without any problems. But in latex it doesn't work, it just removes all indentation. How can I fix this?

All I want is for this feature to work. I think that there is a package called latexindent but I am not sure how to install this. Is there an easy fix?

Comment: `latexindent` is a perl script. `texdoc latexindent` for the docs or look on CTAN. Unless sublime can somehow use this, though, it isn't going to help you while editing. You can indent the source and then open it for editing, but you want your editor to be helping while you are working. No package can do this. It is up to your editor. Or maybe there's a config file or plugin for LaTeX support. Otherwise, you need to choose an editor which supports the feature you want.

Comment: thanks, so far I have only found that emacs works. Although emacs confuses me a lot.

Comment: Kile does indentation, vim. Most TeX-specific editors will do it.

Comment: There is the [BeautifyLatex](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BeautifyLatex), which uses `latexindent`. You can also tweak around with the default indentation rules [LaTeXTools#682](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/682), but that is less powerful. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @r-stein Ubuntu